# Copy contents of Swift Array to Struct embedded Tuple

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, tuples, slice

For communicating with a BLE characteristic, I have a Swift struct that looks like:

```
struct Packet {
    var control1:UInt8 = 0
    var control2:UInt8 = 0
    var payload:(UInt8,UInt8,UInt8,UInt8,UInt8,UInt8,UInt8,UInt8,UInt8,UInt8,UInt8,UInt8,UInt8,UInt8,UInt8,UInt8) = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

    init(control1:UInt8, control2:UInt8) {
        self.control1 = control1
        self.control2 = control2
    }
}
```

I have `payload` defined as a tuple, because that seems to be the only way to have an array (of bytes in this case) of fixed size embedded in a Swift struct. Verbose, but whatever.

I have a big ol' `source:[UInt8]` that I want to pull swatches of into that `Packet` struct, so I can send them via BLE to the remote device. When I do:

```
var packet = Packet(control1: self.pageIndex, control2: sentenceIndex)
let offset = (Int(self.pageIndex) * self.pageSize) + (Int(sentenceIndex) * self.sentenceSize)
let limit = offset + self.sentenceSize
packet.payload = self.source[offset..<limit]
```

For the last line, I get the rather confusing error:

```
Cannot subscript a value of type '[UInt8]'
```

Cryptic I say, because it actually can. If I take the assignment to the `packet.payload` out, it has no problem subscripting the value.

What I'm really interested in at a higher level, is how one puts together a struct with a fixed size array of bytes, and then copies swatches of a large buffer into those. I would like to both understand the above, as well as know how to solve my problem.

UPDATE:

I ended up backing up a little, influenced by both answers below, and rethinking. My main driving force was that I wanted a simple/clever way to have convert a struct with an internal array to/from NSData, primary in BLE communications. What I ended up doing was:

```
struct Packet {
    var pageIndex:UInt8 = 0
    var sentenceIndex:UInt8 = 0
    var payload:ArraySlice<UInt8> = []

    var nsdata:NSData {
        let bytes:[UInt8] = [self.pageIndex, self.sentenceIndex] + self.payload
        return NSData(bytes: bytes, length: bytes.count)
    }
}
```

Not the most efficient because I have to create the intermediate [UInt8] array, but I decided that a simple way to convert didn't exist, that I'd have to do things with as conversions or memcpy and friends.

I'm not sure which of the two below to mark as an answer, since both influenced what I ended up with.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ugly/simple solutions:

- To assign each member of the tuple separately:

  ```
  var offset = ...
  packet.payload = (source[offset++], source[offset++], ... , source[offset++])
  ```
- To just copy the raw memory (recommended)

  ```
  var values = Array(source[offset..<limit])
  memcpy(&packet.payload, &values, sentenceSize)
  ```

Note that it's possible to create an array from a tuple:

```
func tupleToArray<T>(tuple: Any, t: T.Type) -> [T] {
    return Mirror(reflecting: tuple).children.flatMap{ $0.value as? T }
}

tupleToArray((1, 2, 3, 4, 5), t: Int.self)  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But the other way around doesn't work, as Swift's reflection is read-only.

Another much more complicated but more beautiful solution would be to use [Dependent Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type), which enables you to have arrays with compile-time known length. Check out [this great blog post](https://bigonotetaking.wordpress.com/2015/09/04/in-which-i-misunderstand-dependent-types/), in which he also mentions [this post on the Apple Developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/13216#11179) which is basically what you'd need:

```
let vector = 3.0 ⋮ 4.0 ⋮ 5.0    // [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
vector[1]                      // 4.0
vector.count                   // 3
sizeofValue(vector)            // 3 * 8 ( same size as a tuple with 3 elements)
```

Comment: Wow. Read "that great blog post". Going to have reread it a couple of times using a Workspace, that's indeed very cool. Feel there's some light bulbs in there.

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't use tuples to create contiguous arrays of memory. Go ahead and use the [UInt8] type.  I would recommend using a `stride` function to create your indices for you like this. You will have to handle the case of your data source not being a multiple of the Packet payload size.

```
struct Packet {
  var control1: UInt8 = 0
  var control2: UInt8 = 0

  static let size = 16
  var payload = [UInt8].init(count: Packet.size, repeatedValue: 0)

  init(control1: UInt8, control2: UInt8) {
    self.control1 = control1
    self.control2 = control2
  }
}

// random values between 0...255
let blob = (0..<(Packet.size * 3)).map{_ in UInt8(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(UInt8.max)))}

for index in 0.stride(through: blob.count - 1, by: Packet.size) {
  var packet = Packet(control1: 4, control2: 5)
  packet.payload[0..<Packet.size] = blob[index..<index + Packet.size]

  print(packet.payload)
}
```

[image]

As far as the `cannot subscript` error, I encountered that too. I suspect that this has changed recently. I was able to eliminate the error by matching the packet indice slice with the data source slice.

**UPDATE**
A commenter correctly pointed out that `Packet` structure contained a reference to an Array and therefore did not meet the OP's need. While I was focused more on iterating through a large data source using `stride`, here is an alternative using an untyped `[UInt8]` for such a simple data structure.

```
// payload size in count of UInt8
let size     = 16
// field offsets
let control1 = 0
let control2 = 1
let payload  = 2..<(2 + size)

// random values between 0...255
let blob = (0..<size * 3).map{_ in UInt8(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(UInt8.max)))}

for index in 0.stride(through: blob.count - 1, by: size) {
  var buffer = [UInt8](count: 2 + size, repeatedValue: 0)
  buffer[control1] = 255
  buffer[control2] = 0
  buffer[payload]  = blob[index..<index + size]

  let data = NSData(bytesNoCopy: &buffer, length: buffer.count, freeWhenDone: false)
  // send data
}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work though, OP wants to send the bytes of his struct over a stream, however this wouldn't work with having the payload as an Array, because then only a reference to the memory where the real data of the array lies is saved in the struct. You can check this by looking at `sizeof(Packet)` which returns 10 bytes for your answer (2 bytes for control1,2 and 8 bytes for the pointer to the array memory), however OP needs to have those 16 bytes directly in the struct, not referenced which gives a total size of 18 bytes

Comment: You are correct. Packet is 16 bytes; 2 for control1/2, 6 zero padding, and 8 for the Array reference. Therefore I have appended an update. See above.